# Compile for multiple calling conventions

Tags: compilation, calling-convention

I'm looking at some Linux code coming out of the Intel compiler. It looks like functions are being compiled for 2 calling conventions at once. The map file has lots of function name pairs like this:

```
0x0000000008000000   __foo
0x0000000008000008   __foo.
```

The offset between the pairs of functions is 4, 8, or 12 bytes. Each of those corresponds to 1, 2, or 3 mov instructions that are moving stack args to registers like this:

```
__foo:
mov     eax, [esp+4]
mov     edx, [esp+8]
__foo.:
push    ebp
...
```

After those instructions, it looks like a function using the regparm convention starts.

Does the Intel compiler generate functions with two different calling conventions and then use whichever entry address is correct for the given caller?

Comment: What options are you using to compile the code?

Comment: I don't know. A customer is providing this code. I'm trying to figure out how to tell them to change their build settings without knowing exactly what they are.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I'd say you have answered yourself to the question:

> Does the Intel compiler generate functions with two different calling
>   conventions and then use whichever entry address is correct for the
>   given caller?

The foo function appears to be declared with the __regcall attribute. My educated guess is that you must probably have your program compiled using Debug profile, as stack frame based calling conventions allows some information to be available more easily.